# Redirect rsync progress output to stdout inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, io-redirection

What I am trying to do is to automate backup of certain directories on external drive. For that I am using following command inside bash script:

```
...
echo "Backing up important data..."
status=$(rsync -aru --update --append --info=progress2 --info=name  $backup_dirs $default_backup >&1 | echo $?)
if [ "$status" -eq "0" ]
...
```

I want that whatever `--info=progress2` displays should be shown on the screen and the exit status should be stored in `status` variable. I tried using `>&1` for that but it doesn't work, but when I use `> file` the progress is written in the file. What is the method to show the progress in `stdout` and what is the error in trying to redirect the progress output to `stdout` while the same progress output is successfully redirected to a file?

Comment: I don't think you want to pipe the STDOUT of rsync to echo. why don't you remove the `echo $?` completely and just check if `[ $? -eq 0 ]`?

Comment: @RobertSeaman Thanks, it works. But why wasn't it redirected to stdout while it did for a file?

Comment: Your STDOUT is being captured in the `status` variable. you could just run the `rsync` command without assigning its output to a vairable.